# Combining two datasets into one and get mean of rows with same attribute for a column

Tags: r, statistics, dataset

I have a problem and strangely I cannot find a solution on internet.

I have two dataset with the following structure:

[image]

I want to combine the two datasets into a new one which contains all the rows of the two datasets (all the movement times), and for the rows with the same value in "Movement_time", I want to get a new row with the mean value of the x attributes.

I've already tried with `rbind` and `dplyr` library functions, without any result.

I'm doing it in R, can you help me solving this problem please?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give data? What did you tried so far? Edit your question!

Comment: Yes, I edited the post. Thanks.

Comment: 1. `merge(..., by="Movement_time", all=TRUE)`  2. calculation of mean.

Comment: Right! I concentrated on doing operations on rows, but actually it can be seen as column too. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First `merge(..., by="Movement_time", all=TRUE)`
then calculation of mean

```
df1 <- data.frame(Movement_time=sample(101:130, 15), x=rnorm(15))
df2 <- data.frame(Movement_time=sample(101:130, 15), x=rnorm(15))

df12 <- merge(df1, df2, by="Movement_time", all=TRUE)
df12$m <- rowMeans(df12[,2:3], na.rm=TRUE)
```